# Error copying directories at command line using cp

Tags: bash, macos, unix, command-line, cp

*Mac OS X Yosemite v.10.10.5.*

I am trying to use the `cp` command to copy one Git directory to another.

This command-line statement:

```
cp -r /path/to/dir/from/ /path/to/dir/to/
```

Returns this error:

```
cp: /path/to/dir/to/.git/objects/00/00ad2afeb304e18870d4509efc89fedcb3f128: Permission denied
```

This error is returned one time each for (what I believe, but haven't verified, is) every file in the directory.

The first time I ran the command it worked properly, as expected, without error. But, without making any changes to any files, the second (and subsequent) times I ran the command, I got the error.

What's going on? And how can I fix this?

Edit:

In response to a question in the comment:

> What does `ls -l /path/to/dir/to/.git/objects/00/00ad2afeb304e18870d4509efc89fedcb3f128` show?

The answer is it shows:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 myusername staff 6151 May 6 00:45 /path/to/dir/to/.git/objects/00/00ad2afeb304e18870d4509efc89fedcb3f128
```

Comment: @anubhava: `-r--r--r--  1 myusername  staff  6151 May  6 00:45 /path/to/dir/to/.git/objects/00/00ad2afeb304e18870d4509efc89fedcb3f128`

Comment: As you can see that file has only read permissions hence `cp` is failing because it need write permission as well

Comment: @anubhava: Two questions. 1. How do I add write permissions? 2. Why did the `cp` command work the first time I tried it?

Comment: 1. You would use the `chmod` command.

Comment: @CarlTashian: Could you please give me a quick example? If it's in an answer below, I would be inclined to accept it.

Comment: @Mowzer: The permissions is not really the main issue. If you're wanting to completely wipe out anything in your destination directories each time the command runs and overwrite then you don't need to `chmod` at all, but rather remove the destination directory if it exists before copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting `Permission Denied` is because you are trying to overwrite a file that already exists in the destination directory that has read only permissions set on it. Since it appears you're trying to overwrite it you could just remove the destination directory if it exists before the copy operation. Also you should use `-R`, not `-r` ...

> Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This
>   implementation
>        supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it
>        does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's.

Using a command such as this should resolve your issue:

```
[[ ! -d dest ]] || rm -rf dest ; cp -R src dest
```

The above checks if `dest` exists; if it does recursively remove it, then copy the `source` to `dest`,

Answer (score 1):

You may want `cp -rp` for this operation. `-p` preserves the user and group IDs associated with the file. Try starting over using `-p` and see if that solves the issue.

Anther reason you might be seeing this issue is if the permission really is denied. That is, if you're trying to copy into a folder owned by another user without superuser privileges.

Comment: Thanks but this answer did not work. I tried both `cp -rp` and `cp -r -p`.

Comment: `cp -f` might be more relevant (though the `-p` is not a bad idea).